# Can I find an object by the value of one of its properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a mother object filled with objects that looks like this:

```
profiles[ slug ] = {
    slug : slug,
    url : url,
    el : $('#' + el),
    position : this.el.position().left
};
```

I want to be able to reference an object in this array by its `position` property. Is there any quick way of doing this, save for iterating over all of them and comparing each object's value to what I'm searching for?

Comment: referencing the object by its position is not a good idea, what if more than 1 object have the same/duplicated position? Also note that, referencing an object should base on some id (identity) which is ensuredly unique. Unless you mean searching for ***objectS*** based on the `position` property.

Comment: Luckily in this case it's guaranteed that the objects I'm searching for have different positions

Comment: Is `this.el.position().left` meant to refer to the `el` property of the object you're creating? If so, that isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore.js has a lot of utilities that help with these types of lookups: http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere

Example code:

```
var result = _.findWhere(profiles, {position: SEARCH_VALUE});
```

Comment: That's really cool, I'm going to have to give underscore JS a peek

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any quick way of doing this, save for iterating over all of them

Yes: you can build/maintain a secondary index where the key is the `position` and the value is the object.

```
index = {};

for (slug in profile) {
    if (profile.hasOwnProperty(slug)) {
        index[profile[slug].position] = profile[slug];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I was just wondering if there is some crazy obscure jQuery/JS method of just selecting it directly using the property value - no such thing?

Comment: No, of course not. Doing this in O(1) time requires a secondary index and the runtime is certainly not going to do this automagically for you.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks! I'll use this method if nothing else pops up